# Expand PrimeNG multiselect by default when clicking in filter icon

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a primeng table and a multiselect dropdown filter for one of the column like "Agent" column in the below example

[primeng table filter](https://primefaces.org/primeng/table/filter)

When we click on the filter icon, "Agent Picker" multiselect dropdown will display. Then we again need to click on the dropdown to see the options and choose for filtering the results.

But my requirement is, as soon as we click on filter icon, the multiselect should display default options open, reducing one click for the user. Is this achievable? Please suggest any idea/reference link. Thanks.

Comment: Try setting [overlayVisible]="true" on the multiselect component.

Comment: Facing an issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74285663/angular-property-binding-issue-when-parent-element-having-ngif-directive-applie

Comment: You found any solution for this? Thanks.